# jQuery - selecting elements from inside a element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, parent-child

let's say I have a markup like this:

```
<div id="foo">
  ...
  <span id="moo">
    ...
  </span>
  ...
</div>
```

and I want to select #moo.

why `$('#foo').find('span')` works, but `$('span', $('#foo'));` doesn't ?

Comment: Why not `$('#moo')` ? ;) Btw. it does work: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/k5X2r/

Comment: I dont' know why but the function I hook to the selected span gets applied to all spans in the page, not just the one inside #foo :(

Comment: What about when you already have the element selected in a var, so for example you start with `var ele = $("div #foo")` how can you get to moo from here (without using array references)

Answer (score 162, accepted):

You can use any one these [starting from the fastest]

```
$("#moo") > $("#foo #moo") > $("div#foo span#moo") > $("#foo span") > $("#foo > #moo")
```

## [Take a look](http://jsfiddle.net/QPwyj/)

Answer (score 103):

Actually, $('#id', this); would select #id at any descendant level, not just the immediate child. Try this instead:

```
$(this).children('#id');
```

or

```
$("#foo > #moo")
```

or

```
$("#foo > span")
```

Comment: That won't select anything because the element has the **ID** `moo`, not the class.

Comment: It's worth noting that `.children()` and `.find()` are similar except that the former travels only one level down the DOM sub-tree.

Answer (score 38):

You can use `find` option to select an element inside another.  For example, to find an element with id **txtName** in a particular div, you can use like

```
var name = $('#div1').find('#txtName').val();
```

Answer (score 11):

Why not just use:

```
$("#foo span")
```

or

```
$("#foo > span")
```

---

`$('span', $('#foo'));` works fine on my machine ;)

Comment: `$($(elementA), 'tr#' + key + ' span')` is not working for me (jQuery 1.10.2)

Answer (score 9):

Have a look here -- **to query a sub-element of an element**:

`$(document.getElementById('parentid')).find('div#' + divID + ' span.child');`

Answer (score 7):

> ....but $('span', $('#foo')); doesn't work?

This method is called as providing [selector context](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#selector-context).

In this you **provide a second argument to the jQuery selector**. It can be any css object string just like you would pass for direct selecting or a jQuery element.

eg.

```
$("span",".cont1").css("background", '#F00');
```

The above line will select all spans within the container having the class named `cont1`.

**[DEMO](https://codepen.io/MohdAbdulMujib/pen/eLJzvE)**

Comment: Thanks for giving the name of the method, really appreciated

Answer (score 2):

both seem to be working.

see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/PSxkS/