# Select first input element with in all div

Tags: jquery

I have a use case where I need to select first input element with in each div and these divs are cotained in a parent div like:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    <input id="field1" " type="text" value="" name="fieldName1">
    <input id="field2" " type="text" value="" name="fieldName2">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="field3" " type="text" value="" name="fieldName3">
    <input id="field4" " type="text" value="" name="fieldName4">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="field5" " type="text" value="" name="fieldName5">
    <input id="field6" " type="text" value="" name="fieldName6">
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update**: I tried `$(".parent :input");` but it gives me all input fields

I need to select all input element whose names are like `fieldName1,fieldName3 and fieldName5`
Any idea will be helpful.

Comment: Tried anything?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808606/jquery-selecting-elements-from-inside-a-element

Comment: I tried `$(".parent :input");` but it gives me all input fields

Comment: Of course it would, because you didn't tell it to return just the first one in each div. Find a selector that will do that for you. You should also state what you tried within the question and not wait for people to prompt you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mdx9dztj/)

```
$('.parent > div').each(function(){
    alert($(this).find('input').first().attr('name'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$.each($(".parent div"), function(index,item) {
    $.each($(":nth-child(1)", this), function(index,item){
        console.log($(this).attr("name"));
    });
});
```