# Get all span by id inside section tag using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Hi I have one section tag used in my page where i have multiple span with different id like below is having one example:

```html
<section class="blog-summary-read col-md-6 col-md-offset-1">
  <span id="spnid2">2</span>
  <span id="spnid3">3</span>
  <span id="spnid4">4</span>
  <span id="spnid5">5</span>
  <span id="spnid6">6</span>
</section>
```

How do i get each span id using jquery?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - selecting elements from inside a element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808606/jquery-selecting-elements-from-inside-a-element)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get all span element and then iterate to get the id.

```js
/** Method 1 : to get as an array **/

console.log(
  // get all span elements have id and within section 
  $('section span[id]')
  // iterate to generate the array of id
  .map(function() {
    // return the id value
    return this.id;
  })
  // get array from jQuery object
  .get()
)

/** Method 2 : just iterating **/

$('section span[id]').each(function() {
  console.log(this.id);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="blog-summary-read col-md-6 col-md-offset-1">
  <span id="spnid2">2</span>
  <span id="spnid3">3</span>
  <span id="spnid4">4</span>
  <span id="spnid5">5</span>
  <span id="spnid6">6</span>
</section>
```

Comment: Pranav, Your solution is perfect i just added this code with each function to get id. var spnid = $(this.id).selector; Because if i am not using selector here getting some other properties also which is not require. Any how thanks for your valuable solution. I am voting your answer.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('span').each(function(i, v) {

  console.log($(this).attr('id'))

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="blog-summary-read col-md-6 col-md-offset-1">
  <span id="spnid2">2</span>
  <span id="spnid3">3</span>
  <span id="spnid4">4</span>
  <span id="spnid5">5</span>
  <span id="spnid6">6</span>
</section>
```

Iterate over each span using `.each()` then get its id using `attr()`

Answer (score 1):

> Using each function u get all span id's

```js
$('.blog-summary-read span').each(function() {
  console.log(this.id);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="blog-summary-read col-md-6 col-md-offset-1">
  <span id="spnid2">2</span>
  <span id="spnid3">3</span>
  <span id="spnid4">4</span>
  <span id="spnid5">5</span>
  <span id="spnid6">6</span>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you have 3 versions to choose from ... this version selects only the spans inside the section with class "blog-summary-read"

```js
var spans = $('span', '.blog-summary-read');
spans.each(function(index, element){
  console.log($(element).attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="blog-summary-read col-md-6 col-md-offset-1">
  <span id="spnid2">2</span>
  <span id="spnid3">3</span>
  <span id="spnid4">4</span>
  <span id="spnid5">5</span>
  <span id="spnid6">6</span>
</section>
```