# How to retrive the value of a DIV element with ID “FullName” and an INPUT field with the ID “FirstName in JavaScript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, get

```
<div id="FullName">
  <input type="text" id="FirstName" value="Srinath"/>
  <input type="text" id="LastName" value="Reddy"/>
</div>
```

How to retrive the value of firstName of div1 I want to print the value Srinath.

Comment: HTML ids are meant to be unique. Please update the code with your attempt.

Comment: where do you want to print it?

Comment: I just need the value of FirstName from the FullName div

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - selecting elements from inside a element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808606/jquery-selecting-elements-from-inside-a-element)

Answer (score 0):

HTML ids are supposed to be unique, and you should always try not to duplicate them. If you reeally want to do that you can do it with the css element in element selector like that:

```
$("#FullName1 #FirstName")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value like this:

```js
var firstName = document.getElementById('FirstName').value;
alert(firstName);
```

```html
<div id="FullName">
  <input type="text" id="FirstName" value="Srinath"/>
  <input type="text" id="LastName" value="Reddy"/>
</div>
```

You can get it also by jQuery like this:

```
$('#FirstName').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this:

$("#FullName  input#FirstName").val(Text);

Answer (score 0):

If in your scenario, you *always want to get value of **first input** contro*l in your `div` having specific id, then you can use following

```
$("#FullName>input").val()
```

> **Output**: Srinath