# jquery - How to select a class within a table row,

Tags: jquery, variables, selection

I have a table whose cells may contain textboxes, radio buttons, checkboxes
I have given each a class - so all textboxes are class "T", checkboxes are class "C" and so on

I want to iterate over all the rows and get the value of each input.
I have tried this

```
function gather() {
    var res = '';
    var table = document.getElementById("tblQ");
    for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
        if (row.style.display !== 'none') {
            $('.T').each(function () {
                if ($.trim($(this).val()) !== '') 
                    res += $(this).attr('id') + '~' + $(this).val() + '\n';
            });
            $('.C').each(function () {
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) 
                    res += $(this).attr('id') + '~1\n';
            });
            $('.R').each(function () {
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) 
                    res += $(this).attr('id') + '~1\n';
            });
        }
    }
    alert(res);
}
```

```
<table id="tblQ">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input id="01" type="text" value="myText" class='T' />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input id='02' type="checkbox" checked class='C' />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p />
<button onClick='gather()'>Test</button>
```

This gives

```
01~myTest
02~1
01~myTest
02~1
```

How do I restrict the ".each" to the class within the current row.

Comment: Why are you mixing vanilla JS with jquery?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery - selecting elements from inside a element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808606/jquery-selecting-elements-from-inside-a-element)

Comment: Why do you use `".C"` when you can go for `'[type="checkbox"]'`? _ also what should be that `$('.R')` ?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what are you building? What's the meaning of `~1`?

Comment: `$('.T').each(` -> `$('.T', row).each(`  (same for .C/.R)  *or*  (equivalent)   `$(row).find(".T").each(`

Comment: Thanks everyone. I solved it with a combination of DarkBee's and Freedomn-m's suggestions. My selector is now   $('#tblQ > tbody > tr').each(function() {
        if ($(this).css('display') !== 'none') {
           $('.T', this).each(function () { and so on